# One of the node can not start the mariadb in Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, mariadb, openstack, haproxy, galera

I have 3 nodes in my cluster, names: `ha-node1, ha-node2, ha-node3`.

The ha-node2 can not start the `mariadb.service` now, before is normal:

[image]

I use the below commands to show logs:

```
[root@ha-node2 ~]# systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2017-07-31 12:00:33 CST; 13min ago
  Process: 59147 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
  Process: 59138 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 31 11:59:02 ha-node2 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jul 31 12:00:33 ha-node2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service start-pre operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 31 12:00:33 ha-node2 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jul 31 12:00:33 ha-node2 systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Jul 31 12:00:33 ha-node2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

And use `journal -xe`:

```
[root@ha-node2 ~]# journalctl -xe
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 attrd[2281]:   notice: Removing all ha-node3 attributes for attrd_peer_change_cb
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 attrd[2281]:   notice: Lost attribute writer ha-node3
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 attrd[2281]:   notice: Removing ha-node3/3 from the membership list
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 attrd[2281]:   notice: Purged 1 peers with id=3 and/or uname=ha-node3 from the membership cache
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 xinetd[1175]: START: mysqlchk pid=66355 from=::ffff:192.168.8.102
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 xinetd[1175]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=66340 duration=0(sec)
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 xinetd[1175]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=66341 duration=0(sec)
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 xinetd[1175]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=66355 duration=0(sec)
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 corosync[1444]:  [TOTEM ] A new membership (192.168.8.102:11184) was formed. Members
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 corosync[1444]:  [QUORUM] Members[1]: 2
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 corosync[1444]:  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 crmd[2285]:   notice: State transition S_ELECTION -> S_INTEGRATION [ input=I_ELECTION_DC cause=C_TIMER_POPPED origin=election_timeout_popped ]
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 crmd[2285]:  warning: FSA: Input I_ELECTION_DC from do_election_check() received in state S_INTEGRATION
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 crmd[2285]:   notice: Notifications disabled
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 corosync[1444]:  [TOTEM ] A new membership (192.168.8.101:11188) was formed. Members joined: 1 3
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 pacemakerd[1675]:    error: Node ha-node1[1] appears to be online even though we think it is dead
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 pacemakerd[1675]:   notice: pcmk_cpg_membership: Node ha-node1[1] - state is now member (was lost)
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 pacemakerd[1675]:    error: Node ha-node3[3] appears to be online even though we think it is dead
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 pacemakerd[1675]:   notice: pcmk_cpg_membership: Node ha-node3[3] - state is now member (was lost)
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 attrd[2281]:   notice: crm_update_peer_proc: Node ha-node1[1] - state is now member (was (null))
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 cib[2277]:   notice: crm_update_peer_proc: Node ha-node1[1] - state is now member (was (null))
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 corosync[1444]:  [QUORUM] This node is within the primary component and will provide service.
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 corosync[1444]:  [QUORUM] Members[3]: 1 2 3
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 corosync[1444]:  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 pacemakerd[1675]:   notice: Membership 11188: quorum acquired (3)
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 stonith-ng[2279]:   notice: crm_update_peer_proc: Node ha-node1[1] - state is now member (was (null))
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 cib[2277]:   notice: crm_update_peer_proc: Node ha-node3[3] - state is now member (was (null))
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 attrd[2281]:   notice: crm_update_peer_proc: Node ha-node3[3] - state is now member (was (null))
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 stonith-ng[2279]:   notice: crm_update_peer_proc: Node ha-node3[3] - state is now member (was (null))
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 crmd[2285]:   notice: Membership 11188: quorum acquired (3)
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 crmd[2285]:   notice: pcmk_quorum_notification: Node ha-node1[1] - state is now member (was lost)
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 crmd[2285]:   notice: pcmk_quorum_notification: Node ha-node3[3] - state is now member (was lost)
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 attrd[2281]:   notice: Recorded attribute writer: ha-node3
Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 attrd[2281]:   notice: Processing sync-response from ha-node3
```

---

**EDIT-1**

I use `clustercheck` to check the status of cluster in the ha-node2, I found the connection is close, and the galera cluster node is not synced:

```
[root@ha-node2 ~]# clustercheck 
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: close
Content-Length: 36

Galera cluster node is not synced.
```

And in the ha-node1 and ha-node3 is connection is close, and galera cluster node is synced:

```
[root@ha-node1 ~]# clustercheck 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: close
Content-Length: 32

Galera cluster node is synced.
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally see issue in message `xinetd[1175]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13`.  From the xinetd man pages it is

```
For services with type =
       INTERNAL, SIGTERM signal will be sent.  For  services  without  type  =
       INTERNAL, SIGKILL signall will be sent.
```

In your case it is `SIGPIPE 13  Write on a pipe with no reader, Broken pipe (POSIX)`

The most likely cause is:
`Jul 31 12:14:49 ha-node2 attrd[2281]:   notice: Lost attribute writer ha-node3`  You have to trace this one to find out what is happening between ha-node2 and ha-node3 (I recommend `tcpdump` for that)
.

I would have to see more of your `mysqlchk` or the script that makes your HAproxy.

If nothing will help you can also try alternative HAClustering solution `https://github.com/olafz/percona-clustercheck`

Comment: How to see the " mysqlchk or the script that makes your HAproxy" ?

Comment: Contents of your xinetd script is viewed via `cat /etc/xinetd.d/mysqlchk`